# Can canvas draw SpannableString text?

Tags: android, android-widget

Can android [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) draw [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) text?

The only method that could *possibly* work is [Canvas#drawText(CharSequence...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) because it is the unique that receives a `CharSequence` text as an argument which is implemented by String and SpannableString.

When it draw I get nothing but blank.

**EDIT:**

I managed to write the `SpannableString` but the spans are gone. I guess the method is not proper for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `SpannableString` only implements `CharSequence` interface. When used in `TextView`, it checks if `input instanceof SpannableString` and if it is, it draws it like that. If not, it draws just simple text.

I've been trying to implement similar behavior like `TextView` in our game, but with no joy. So I've ended up with implementing something similar, class that holds multiple classes in `List`. Those define the text and style. Then I have a method `StyledText.draw(Canvas)` and it goes through the `List`, using the `Canvas.drawText( ... )` to draw each text. It handles positioning and creating/modifying instance of `Paint`.

Comment: DeToX, thanks for replying! I digged in a lot at the `TextView` source code before. I made a custom view from the ground extending `View` so I had to handle all measurements, drawing and handling some events. The point was optimizing our app code, reducing code verbosity and learning of course. I used a `StaticLayout` and a couple of `DynamicLayout`. Have you tried playing with those in your game?

Comment: No I didn't. I ended up with 1) exporting the whole bitmap with static text or 2) left out some cool looking things (like numbers made bold and the rest normal, now it's all bold or normal). I'll check the dynamic and static layouts for sure. The thing is, that you need to draw it just once a while right? I need it like 60 times a second and that's why I often make decisions in favor of performance and not design. (PS: Sorry for my English, I'm not native speaker)